# QGIS- What is the meaning of the Query Builder operators?

Tags: qgis, query, operator

I am learning to filter my data, and I understand how to use the basic operators (e.g. =, OR, AND, !=, less than, more than etc) however there are some operators that are less obvious.

What do the following mean in the query builder operators section?

- LIKE
- ILIKE
- %
- IN
- NOT
- NOT IN

And how might they be used in an expression?

Comment: Have you had a look at the explanations and examples attached to these expressions? If so, what is left unclear?

Comment: Where might I find these explanations? They are not in the Query Builder window in QGIS, and I couldn't find anything in the QGIS user guide!

Comment: To be fair the Query Builder of the Provider Feature Filter doesn't have in-build help section (and the help button send me to a non existant page...) but if you go to select feature by expression (or any other place where you could use an expression) you will access the expression builder if you select the Operator menu and click on an operator the description should appear on the right side of the window. these operator should work the same anywhere you use it on QGIS.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @J.R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They all have short explanations when you click on them in the Expression String Builder.

For IN:

[image]

Comment: That's not the same window I have in QGIS 3.4!

Comment: @Phoebe See my comment on your question

Comment: The filter tool has a different layout, that is more restrictive. You can get this tool, for example from: the attribute table, and "Select features using an expression".